# How to get everything before and up to a certain substring within a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

How would I return a string up to a certain character?

```
def get_header(s):
    '''(str) -> str
    Return the start of the given string upto and including
    </head>.'''
    return (s.split('</head>')[0])
```

this is what i did but, I don't know how i would get everything before the "  "<"/heads">"" and including it.

for example:

```
s ="hello python world </head> , i'm a beginner "
get_header(s)
```

this would return

```
"hello python world "<"/head">"   #without the quotient marks around the <
```

Comment: post a sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, but won't include `"</head>"`, so just add it at the end:

```
def get_header(s):
    '''(str) -> str
    Return the start of the given string upto and including
    </head>.'''
    return s.split('</head>')[0] + "</head>"
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a fairly easy thing to do with Python's [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) module which matches a "regular expression" (or regex) to a string.

Here's how to use it to do what you want:

```
import re

def get_header(s):
    """(str) -> str
    Return the start of the given string upto and including </head>.
    """
    matches = re.search(r".*</head>", s)
    return matches.group(0) if matches else None

s = "hello python world </head> , i'm a beginner "
print(get_header(s))  # -> hello python world </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party library that implements a [`split_after`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.split_after) tool.  Install via:

```
> pip install more_itertools
```

**Given**

```
import more_itertools as mit


s = "hello python world </head> , i'm a beginner "
```

**Code**

```
pred = lambda x: x == "</head>"
" ".join(next(mit.split_after(s.split(), pred)))
# 'hello python world </head>'
```

The string is split by spaces into "words".  The full string is split after any words that suit the predicate.  The first result is joined together.