# How to get a header from a html file

Tags: python, html

I am having difficulty in understanding what exactly I am suppose to do for my homework question.

The question states... Given a str, return the entire substring starting at the beginning of the str up to and including . Requirement:
The string contains .

```
The code is...
def get_header(s):
'''(str) -> str
Return the start of the given string up to and including</head>.'''
```

Here is a small segment snippet of the html file example I am suppose to use for this code....

```
 <html>
            <head>
                <style>
    body {
        background: black;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        }
```

Is this question asking me to only read the first two html lines or do I have to find all headers throughout the html files?

Thank you, any help would be appreciated,

Ned

Comment: We didn't set your homework. You're going to have to ask your teacher. But if I were to guess, they probably only meant one.

Comment: I feel you have to output everything between the given string and </head> tag

Comment: 1. Stack Overflow is not a site for your homework. At least put some effort and show us what you have tried. 2. One of your fellow classmates has just asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320404/how-to-get-everything-before-and-up-to-a-certain-substring-within-a-string). You can thank me later.

Comment: @Foxan Ng. I just wanted clarification on the question but I understand where you're coming from, well thanks for the feedback and  the tag lol.

Answer (score -1):

using js:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0];
var y = x.outerHTML
```